# How to extract exact tags in scrapy

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, scrapy, extract

I wrote a class for scrapy in order to get the piece of content of a page like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import html2text
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector


class StockSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "stock_spider"
    allowed_domains = ["www.hamshahrionline.ir"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.hamshahrionline.ir/details/261730/Health/publichealth"]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
#       sample = hxs.select("WhatShouldIputHere").extract()[AndHere]
        converter = html2text.HTML2Text()
        converter.ignore_links = True
        print converter.handle(sample)
```

My main problem is the state that I commented it.

How can I set path and extract parameter for that?

Can you guide me over this and give me some examples?

Thank you

Comment: `HtmlXPathSelector` is deprecated. Use `Selector`. See this guide for several examples: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to decide what data do you want to get out of the page, define an [`Item`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html) class and a set of [`Field`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html#item-fields)s. Then, in order to fill item fields with data, you need use `xpath` expressions in the `parse()` method of your spider.

Here's an example that retrieves all of the paragraphs out of the body (all news, I suppose):

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector


class MyItem(Item):
    content = Field()


class StockSpider(Spider):
    name = "stock_spider"
    allowed_domains = ["www.hamshahrionline.ir"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.hamshahrionline.ir/details/261730/Health/publichealth"]

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        paragraphs = sel.xpath("//div[@class='newsBodyCont']/p/text()").extract()
        for p in paragraphs:
            item = MyItem()
            item['content'] = p
            yield item
```

Note that I'm using a [`Selector`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#scrapy.selector.Selector) class since `HtmlXPathSelector` is deprecated. Also, I'm using [`xpath()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#scrapy.selector.Selector.xpath) method instead of `select()` because of the same reason.

Also, note that you'd better extract your `Item` definition in a separate python script to follow the [Scrapy project structure](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#creating-a-project).

Hope that helps.