# Extracting HTML content

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I have extracted below HTML content from an URL using Scrapy

```
<div id="data">
       <div style="position:absolute">
            <h4 class="course">Python</h4>
            <h4 class="count">45</h4>
       </div>
       <h1 style="position:absolute">Available</h1>
       <h2 style="position:absolute">Weekend</h1>
       <h1 style="position:absolute">Paid Version</h1>
</div>
```

and using xpath

```
headerResponse = response.xpath('//div[@id="data"]').extract()
```

I have loaded them into headerResponse variable. Now I want to get  value, since it doesnt have id or class how to extract them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24101061/how-to-extract-exact-tags-in-scrapy)

Comment: What is your desired output?